# "Average" of Cartesian coordinate systems

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, rotations, average

Having two Cartesian coordinate systems:

```
C1(X1,Y1,Z1)
C2(X2,Y2,Z2)
```

(where X1,Y1,Z1 and X2,Y2,Z2 are orthogonal unit vectors)

Is it possible to have a third Cartesian coordinate system `C3(X3,Y3,Z3)` as an "average" of these?

Making a component-wise average `X3=X1+X2`, `Y3=Y1+Y2` and `Z3=Z1+Z2` (followed by normalization), could result in a zero component, if e.g. `X1=-X2`. Is there a better way, using perhaps circular means or using rotation matrixes and finding a half-way rotation between `C1` and `C2` that leads to `C3`?

(Or am I asking the wrong question? I couldn't find any quick answers online)

Comment: This sounds like you just want the midpoint. Also, it's not "coordinate system," just "coordinates." A coordinate system defines how points are graphed (cf. polar coordinates, cylindrical coordinates, ...)

Comment: I am referring to coordinate systems (or coordinate frames), specifically Cartesian coordinate systems, with 3 orthogonal unit vectors being the axes in a 3D space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relate the two coordinate frames by a rotation matrix, that is, find the relative rotation matrix $R$ such that

$ R_2 = R R_1 $

where $R_1$ is the rotation matrix whose columns are the unit vectors along the $X_1, Y_1, Z_1$ axes of the first frame, and similarly for $R_2$.

Identify the axis and rotation angle of $R$, then take half of that rotation angle to generate the average of $R_1$ and $R_2$.

The identification of $R$ relies on the Rodrigues' formulation of a rotation matrix, namely

$R = a a^T + (I - a a^T) \cos \theta + S_a \sin \theta $

Here $a$ is the unit vector along the axis of rotation, $\theta$ is the angle of rotation, and $S_a$ is defined as

$ S_a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - a_z && a_y \\ a_z && 0 && - a_x \\ -a_y && a_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Note that if add the diagonal elements of $R$ (the trace of $R$) you get

$ R_{11} + R_{22} + R_{33} = 1 + \cos \theta (3 - 1) = 1 + 2 \cos \theta $

Thus you get the rotation angle immediately.  Next we want to find the coordinates of the unit vector $a$ (the axis), and this can be done by using the fact that the first two terms in the Rodrigues' formula are symmetric matrices while the third is skew-symmetric.  So by taking the difference:

$ R_{12} - R_{21} = -2 a_z \sin \theta $

and similarly for the other off-diagonal entries.

Once $a$ and $\theta$ are known, generate the rotation matrix corresponding to $\dfrac{\theta}{2} $, while keeping the same axis.

Plug these values in the Rodrigues' formula, to get $R_{ \theta/2} $, and finally the average coordinate frame will be

$ R_{av} = R_{ \theta /2} R_1$

The columns of $R_{av} $ are the average $X, Y, Z$ axes.

Comment: What would you recommend to "average"  3 or more coordinate systems?